# Zend 2 + Dojo documentation…

Tags: zend-framework, dojo

i'm starting using Zend 2 + Dojo. I can't find tutorials to start with these, i only find blogs about Zend 1.9 and the official Zend_Dojo docs is quite poor. Any help nor good link right here? :)

ty a lot!

Answer (score 2):

your "Problem" in this case is, that the Dojo Framework was included in Zend Framework 1.x with some ViewHelpers, Form-Elements and more.

In Zend Framework 2, Dojo is not included. Just use Dojo like you would without Zend Framework :-)